# Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'REPLACE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I don't know why but suddenly I getting the following error.

Till now it is working fine but today it will produce the following error
[image]

it is working fine when I test to the local server but when I uploaded to 000webhost server it will produce an error

> Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of
>   'REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( @@sql_mode'
>   SELECT `vValue` FROM `configurations` WHERE `eStatus` = 'Active' AND `vName` = > 'PAGE_DATA_LIMIT' ORDER BY `iSettingId` DESC

At `Filename: core/MY_Model.php` all code is working fine there is no error on `Line Number: 94` which is displayed

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open file config/database.php 
and change value's variable stricton to be 'TRUE'

```
'stricton' => TRUE,
```

Comment: Can you please explain what it changes & what is the usage. Thanks.

Comment: so, TRUE/FALSE (boolean) - Whether to force “Strict Mode” connections, good for ensuring strict SQL while developing an application.
sorry i didnt give any information, 

i just read documentation's code igniter : 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

No idea why this throws. But you can temporarily bypass it by setting `sql_mode` to null

```
$this->db->query("SET sql_mode = '' ");
//rest of your DB codes
```

Answer (score 1):

before you import sql file to database(mysql)

change line

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
```

to be

```
SET SQL_MODE = "";
```