# Database Error No. 1231 on 000webhost website

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

my website was working fine since i uploaded it a year ago. but a few days ago i suddenly get the error message 1231 in my 000webhost.com website. the error comes either right when i open my website or after i navigate through it. can anybody help? has anybody experience with this error? what could be the cause? and how to solve it?

i thought i can fix it by updating my codeigniter 3.1.7 to the latest version 3.1.10., but it didnt help. i changed the php version from 7.2 to 7.0 and later to 5.6, also made no difference.

libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php and mysql_driver.php

```
    /**
     * Validate ID
     *
     * Checks whether a session ID record exists server-side,
     * to enforce session.use_strict_mode.
     *
     * @param   string  $id
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function validateSessionId($id)
    {
        // Prevent previous QB calls from messing with our queries
        $this->_db->reset_query();

        $this->_db->select('1')->from($this->_config['save_path'])->where('id', $id);
        empty($this->_config['match_ip']) OR $this->_db->where('ip_address', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $result = $this->_db->get();
        empty($result) OR $result = $result->row();

        return ! empty($result);
    }

/**
 * Database connection
 *
 * @param   bool    $persistent
 * @return  object
 */
public function db_connect($persistent = FALSE)
{
    // Do we have a socket path?
    if ($this->hostname[0] === '/')
    {
        $hostname = NULL;
        $port = NULL;
        $socket = $this->hostname;
    }
    else
    {
        $hostname = ($persistent === TRUE)
            ? 'p:'.$this->hostname : $this->hostname;
        $port = empty($this->port) ? NULL : $this->port;
        $socket = NULL;
    }

    $client_flags = ($this->compress === TRUE) ? MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS : 0;
    $this->_mysqli = mysqli_init();

    $this->_mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    if (isset($this->stricton))
    {
        if ($this->stricton)
        {
            $this->_mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ",", "STRICT_ALL_TABLES")');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND,
                'SET SESSION sql_mode =
                REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                @@sql_mode,
                "STRICT_ALL_TABLES,", ""),
                ",STRICT_ALL_TABLES", ""),
                "STRICT_ALL_TABLES", ""),
                "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,", ""),
                ",STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", ""),
                "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", "")'
            );
        }
    }
```

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1231

Variable ‘sql_mode’ can’t be set to the value of ‘REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( @@sql_mode’

SELECT 1 FROM ci_sessions WHERE id = ‘9mk3avf3kaocstm4rrcappec902q2msi’ AND ip_address = ‘x.x.x.x’

Filename: libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php

Line Number: 363

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable 'sql\_mode' can't be set to the value of 'REPLACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57375512/variable-sql-mode-cant-be-set-to-the-value-of-replace)

Comment: @aynber iam more tempted to comment **not running MySQL in strict mode always is asking for trouble** after reading the code..

Comment: what should i change?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Very true. I have no idea what CodeIgnitor has for the settings, but tweaking the settings would help. I'd suggest start with the empty string and then add each setting back in one at a time to see what works

Comment: check where `$this->stricton` is set and set it to be true (most likely database.php) like @aynber suggested..   Or edit the codeigniter code so it executes  `SET SESSION sql_mode = (REPLACE ...)` i assume that also should do the trick but ideally you should not be editing framework code..

Comment: i set the stritcon to TRUE but that made it even worse. i wonder why this happens so suddenly, over 1 year this setup was working fine and now suddenly it wont work anymore. very strange.

Comment: i tried to set stritcon to TRUE again, got an error message "Field 'user_agent' doesn't have a default value" so i changed it to NULL and now it works. thanks!!! for the time being problem solved! hope it stays that way! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open file applications/config/database.php 
change variable stricton to TRUE

```
'stricton' => TRUE,
```

Comment: yes, thanks, i did that. got more error messages at first, i managed to fix the first one and all others disappeared and now everything works fine again!!! thanks to you all!!!